# Convergence of the series with $a_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1} \cdot n^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \cdot (n-1)^2} +\cdot\cdot\cdot + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} \cdot 1^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to determine the convergence of the series whose general term is given by:
$$a_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1} \cdot n^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \cdot (n-1)^2} +\cdot\cdot\cdot + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} \cdot 1^2}$$
**Observation**

1. $\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}} \lt a_n \lt \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2 }$
2. $a_n$ is monotonic decreasing sequence and converges to zero.

This series is bigger than a convergent and smaller than a divergent series by the second observation, if I have not incorrectly done. But its of no help here to determine the convergence. Kindly help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $$
a_n  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {n - k + 1} }}} 
$$ and $$
\frac{1}{{k^2 }}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {n - k + 1} }} \le \frac{1}{{k^2 }},\quad \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}  <  + \infty,
$$ you can use [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem).

Comment: Would appreciate if you kindly elaborate it in an answer.

Comment: I gave you enough information (including the link to the Wikipedia page). You should be able to complete the proof yourself.

Comment: Do u have any idea of the possible limit?

Comment: You can also use the second case of [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) with $$
a_k  := \frac{1}{{\sqrt {n - k + 1} }},\quad b_k  := \frac{1}{{k^2 }}.
$$ (this $a_k$ is different from your $a$)

Comment: @Gary I am thinking about a way which is based on using definite integral on `[0,1]`.

Comment: @Gary The question is about the series and not the sequence.

Comment: @Mikasa I guess you cannot transform the given expression into a Riemann sum, since the only natural function would be $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{1-x}}$ which is not integrable over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for the resources.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ah, I totally misread the question. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. One has

\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^2}\right) &= \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^2\sqrt{k}}\\
&\leq \sum_{n=2}^{2N} \sum_{j+k=n} \frac{1}{j^2\sqrt{k}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} \sum_{j+k=n+1} \frac{1}{j^2\sqrt{k}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(n+1-k)^2}\\
\end{align*}

So you get that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} a_n \geq \left( \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^2}\right) $$

and because $\displaystyle{\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}$ is divergent and $\displaystyle{\sum \frac{1}{j^2}}$ is convergent, you get that
$$\boxed{\text{the series }\sum a_n \text{ diverges}.}$$

**Edit :** This gives a precise estimation of the partial sum of the series $\sum a_n$, but as @PeterSzilas noticed, the divergence can be obtained much more directly by noticing that
$$a_n \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Pardon if it seems trivial, but how to get $a_n \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ? Would be grateful if elaborated a bit.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha The last term of $a_n$ is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Should we have this @TheSilverDoe ?
\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^2}\right) &= \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^2\sqrt{k}}\\
& \lt \sum_{n=2}^{2N} \sum_{j+k=n} \frac{1}{j^2\sqrt{k}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} \sum_{j+k=n+1} \frac{1}{j^2\sqrt{k}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(n+1-k)^2}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha No, if you sum over the values of the sum $j+k$, then this sum goes from $2$ to $2N$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Fond of your way! +

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  $N=2$ in $\sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} a_n = \left( \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^2}\right) $ is giving:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt1\cdot 1^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt1\cdot 2^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2\cdot 1^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt1\cdot 3^2} +  \frac{1}{\sqrt2\cdot 2^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt3\cdot 1^2} \neq (\frac{1}{ 1^2} + \frac{1}{ 2^2})\cdot (  \frac{1}{\sqrt 1} + \frac{1}{ \sqrt 2})$
Where am I missing it? :(

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha Oh, you are right. The problem comes from the fact that in the sum $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=2}^{2N} \sum_{j+k=n} \frac{1}{j^2\sqrt{k}}}$ (second line), one should also add that $j,k \leq N$. So indeed, a good way to correct it is to change the $=$ into a $\leq$, as you suggested (which does not make the proof collaspe). I edited, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

$S_N= \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(n+1-k)^2}$

we have

$1\leq k \leq n\leq N$

So

$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{n=k}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\frac{1}{(n+1-k)^2}$

$= \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \left(\sum_{n=k}^N \frac{1}{(n+1-k)^2}\right)$

But

$\sum_{n=k}^N \frac{1}{(n+1-k)^2}\geq \int_{1}^{N-k+2} \frac{1}{x^2}dx
\geq 1-\frac{1}{N-k+2}\geq\frac12$

$S_N\geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$